# How to get Continuous futures data stitched from individual contracts with intraday data points (Tick data)

Tags: python

After simply concatenating two csv files, I have created a single Dataframe so that by using matplotlib library I can plot the data. but the problem is that the chart which shows up is complete mess.

The chart looks like this
[on the left (vertical) are the prices whereas on x axis it is actually time period which starts from 9:15 A.M to 3:30 P.M (IST)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdyLH.png)

what I actually want is as below
[please play close attention to x axis where time period is mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CmQH.png)

observe the first data point on x axis which is 9.15.25 and the other data point which is 9.25.04 along the same axis.

How can I create a chart which would look very similar to the other chart which I have created in excel

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what if you plot only one CSV? if it looks good then problem is because you concatenate them. maybe they have the same values `X` - maybe you have to add `date` to `time`